# Laravel Eloquent - relation of relation - three model relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, model, relation

I am trying to convert the below DB query to an eloquent relation.

```
$device_barcodes = ["BSC0337", "BSC0503", "BSC0626"];
$devices = DB::table('devices')
       ->leftjoin('devices_repairs', 'devices_repairs.device_id', '=', 'devices.device_id')
       ->leftJoin('staff','staff.staff_id','devices_repairs.repair_damaged_by')
       ->whereIn('barcode', $device_barcodes)
       ->get();
```

So far I have the below, but I am struggling with the staff relation.

```
$devices = Devices::with('repairDetails')->whereIn('barcode', $device_barcodes)->get();
```

I've overcome this for now with the below, but this is not ideal.

```
foreach($devices as $device) {
           $staff_name = Staff::find($device->repairDetails->repair_damaged_by);
           $device->staff_name = $staff_name->staff_name;
 }
```

I am hoping for something like:

```
$devices = Devices::with('repairDetails')->with('staffDetails')->whereIn('barcode', $device_barcodes)->get();
```

This way I can show the device details, the repair details and the staff name on my blade form.

So the basic issue is I am trying to relate three models together.

Devices is the top model, where I join with DevicesRepairs using the device_id primary and foreign keys. But for the Staff model I need to join devices_repairs.repair_damaged by to staff.staff_id.

Here are my models:
Devices:

```
class Devices extends Model
{
    /**
     * @var bool $timestamps Disable timestamps
     */
    public $timestamps = false;
    /**
     * @var string $table Name of the db table
     */
    protected $table = 'devices';
    /**
     * @var string $primaryKey Name of the primary key
     */
    protected $primaryKey = 'device_id';
    /**
     * @var array $fillable The attributes that are mass assignable.
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'status',
        'order_reference',
        'model',
        'serial',
        'imei',
        'barcode',
        'mobile_number',
        'helpdesk_url_id',
        'device_notes'
    ];

    use Searchable;

    function repairDetails() {
        return $this->hasOne(DevicesRepairs::class, 'device_id');
    }

    function repairHistoryDetails() {
        return $this->hasOne(DevicesRepairsHistory::class, 'device_id');
    }

}
```

DevicesRepairs:

```
class DevicesRepairs extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = 'devices_repairs';
    protected $primaryKey = 'device_id';
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $fillable = [
        'device_id',
        'repair_damanged_by',
        'repair_damage_type',
        'repair_date_received',
        'repair_date_sent_for',
        'repair_damage_notes',
        'repairer_name',
        'repair_is_user_damage',
        'job_number',
        'operator_date_received',
        'operator_date_received_by',
        'operator_date_sent',
        'operator_sent_by',
        'photo_id',
        'photo_id_back'
    ];

    function device() {
        return $this->hasOne(Devices::class, 'device_id');
    }

    //This doesn't work - seems to return a random staff member.
    function staffDetails() {
        return $this->hasOne(Staff::class,'staff_id','repair_damaged_by');
    }  
}
```

Staff:

```
class Staff extends Model
{
    use searchable;

    /**
     * @var bool $timestamps Disable timestamps
     */
    public $timestamps = false;
    /**
     * @var string $table Name of the db table
     */
    protected $table = 'staff';
    /**
     * @var string $primaryKey Name of the primary key
     */
    protected $primaryKey = 'staff_id';
    /**
     * @var array $fillable The attributes that are mass assignable.
     */

    protected $fillable = [
        'staff_id',
        'staff_name',
        'manager_id',
        'is_active',
        'is_mdm_user',
        'user_id',
    ];
}
```

My ultimate aim is to be able to return fields like this in my view:

```
{{$device->barcode}}
{{$device->repairDetails->repair_damage_notes}}

//The above work fine but not this:
{{$device->staffDetails->staff_name}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

treat at as a pivot table, a many to many relation between devices and staff

```
class Devices extends Model
{
    public function damagedBy()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Staff::class, 'devices_repairs', 'device_id', 'repair_damaged_by');
    }
```

So the query will be like

```
$device_barcodes = ["BSC0337", "BSC0503", "BSC0626"];
$devices = Devices::with('damagedBy')->whereIn('barcode', $device_barcodes)->get();
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This worked. It seems it is returned as an array so needed to do this for it to display in my view but otherwise it works great. Still getting my head around relations. $device->damagedBy[0]->staff_name

Comment: @masterg174 it returns an array cause that's what your database structure suggests. a device can be repaired multiple times so it can have multiple "damagedBy"s, on for each repair.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Although in my case, I actually have a separate repairs history table for storing historical repairs once the repair is complete. As devices are unique only one instance of a particular device (PK:device_id) can be stored in the repairs table at one time. I found this also to work:    $devices = Devices::with('repairDetails')->with('repairDetails.staffDetails')->whereIn('barcode', $device_barcodes)->get();

Comment: @masterg174 then why not have the foreign key staff_id directly in the tables devices ?

Comment: That's a good point actually - that could then work for all sub type tables such as assigned, repairs, destroyed etc. Although at this stage, the system is already in production so not sure if it's feasible to change DB structure, but something to think about. In any case both solutions solved my issue and you certainly pointed me in the right direction so I am happy. Thanks again!